# Ошибка при установки Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

`composer create-project laravel/laravel docker-laravel`

[image: фото с ошибкой]

Сообщение ошибок

> Failed to download laravel/laravel from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
> The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\PHP\php.ini
> Now trying to download from source

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
> packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно включить расширение php_zip.dll в php.ini и перезапустить сервер.